# Django DecimalField: remove Decimal('x') at the output when stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, model, decimal

I want to export a Python dictionary to a JSON file via `json.dumps()`. 
The data is collected using a Django modelfield "DecimalField" which is using the python decimal datatype.

The problem now is, that the data inside the dictionary is presented like:

`'interval': Decimal('2')`

and the json.dumps() cannot handle this because of this Decimal string.

Is there any possibility to remove the "Decimal" from the output and just display the number like `'interval': 2` ? Or do I need to change all my ModelFields to Float/Integer?